# Using locally develop npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, umd

I have developed a nodejs project as an umd library, with the purpose to use it in a another nodejs project. The library project builds fine and generates the index.js file and index.min.js file.

But when I tried installing the library project locally using npm install "asolute path". It brings all the things in the library project. And the size of my project I want to use the library project grew. Seems it is because of all the files in library project is getting copied.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an [`.npmignore` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)?

Also, you'll probably want to use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#link-packages) for local development.

Comment: no I haven't used npmignore. I will search for that now